# Черепашка - C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Что я не правильно делаю в этой задаче? Помогите пожалуйста!

В таблице размером `N*N` клетки заполнены случайным образом числами от –100 до 100. Напишите программу, которая поможет черепашке найти маршрут из самой нижней левой клетки в самую верхнюю правую клетку и удовлетворяющий следующим условиям:

Если клетки таблицы перенумеровать сверху вниз и слева направо, то из клетки `(i,j)` (`i` - строка, `j` - столбец) черепашка может перейти в клетки вверх - `(i–1,j)`, вправо вверх - `(i–1,j+1)` и вправо - `(i,j+1)`, не выходя, конечно, за границы таблицы.

Нужно найти маршрут с максимальной суммой чисел в клетках маршрута.

*Входные данные*

В первой строке входных данных задано одно натуральное число `N` (`N <= 100`). В следующих `N` строках заданы числа в клетках таблицы.

Выходные данные

Одно число – максимальная сумма в клетках искомого маршрута.

*Информация*
Лимит времени: 1 секунды
Предел памяти: 64 Mb
Баллы: 10
Уровень сложности: 6/67 (91 %)

Пример
Пример входных данных

```
3
1 2 3
-4 15 -6
7 -8 9
```

Пример выходных данных:  `27`

```
int a[MAXN][MAXN];
int d[MAXN][MAXN];

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    memset(a, -1, sizeof(a));

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

    d[n][1] = a[n][1];

    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            d[i][j] = max(d[i][j + 1], max(d[i - 1][j + 1],
                                           d[i - 1][j])) + a[i][j];
            // cout<<max(a[i][j+1],a[i-1][j+1])<<endl;
        }

    printf("%d", d[n][n]);
```

Comment: Так черепашка или Чебурашка?

Answer (score 3):

Откровенно говоря, разбираться лень; похоже, вы не в том направлении смотрите клетки, откуда попадаете в данную, а кроме того, не рассматриваете случаи, когда попасть в данную клетку просто неоткуда.

Попробуйте посмотреть отсюда:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<vector<int>> a(N,vector<int>(N,0));
    vector<vector<int>> d(N,vector<int>(N,0));
    for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < N; c++) cin >> a[r][c];

    for(int r = N-1; r >= 0; r--)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {
            d[r][c] = a[r][c];

            int v = numeric_limits<int>::min();
            if (c-1 >= 0)
            {
                if (v < d[r][c-1]) v = d[r][c-1];
            }
            if (r+1 < N)
            {
                if (v < d[r+1][c]) v = d[r+1][c];
            }
            if ((c-1 >= 0) && (r+1 < N))
            {
                if (v < d[r+1][c-1]) v = d[r+1][c-1];
            }
            if (v != numeric_limits<int>::min())
            {
                d[r][c] += v;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << d[0][N-1] << endl;
}
```

И еще - как-то у вас задача изложена сумбурно. Обычно сначала в координатах идет `x`, потом `y`, у вас - сначала строка, потом столбец... То Чебурашка, то черепашка :)

Словом, мне пришлось плясать от решения. а не от задачи :(

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: Если устраивает - принимайте как ответ на вопрос...

Comment: можете подробно описать ваш код ?

Comment: Нет, простите, код сам себя описывает. Иду построчно снизу вверх, по строкам слева направо; смотрю, откуда можно попасть в данную клетку (все эти if'ы), ищу максимальное значение... Все. То же, что хотели (если я верно понял) сделать вы.

Comment: В исходной реализации специально сделана нумерация с 1, а не с 0, чтобы не замусоривать код этими вашими if-ами, а использовать "лишние" строку и столбец в качестве guard elements с нулевым значением. Они естественно вписываются в алгоритм и позволяют не беспокоиться о "попасть в данную клетку просто неоткуда".

Comment: @AnT Тогда их надо заполнять не нулями, а отрицательными значениями поменьше минимально возможного по условию - иначе, если нижний ряд один другого отрицательнее, можно получить ерунду.

Comment: @Harry: Да, верно! Я упустил этот момент.

Answer (score 2):

Вы, очевидно, выбрали способ нумерации `[i][j]` (`i` - строка, а `j` - столбец), в котором строки нумеруются сверху-вниз, а столбцы - слева-направо.

Тогда ваши циклы заполняют матрицу `d` в порядке слева-направо снизу-вверх. То есть матрица `d` инициализируется вычисленными значениями из левого-нижнего угла наружу.

Но при этом на каждой итерации ваша формула

```
d[i][j] = max(d[i][j + 1], max(d[i - 1][j + 1], d[i - 1][j])) + a[i][j];
```

проверяет *правых и верхних* соседей текущей точки. Но эти элементы матрицы `d` еще не получили осмысленные значения! Там сидят начальные нули.

Ваша формула развернута не в ту сторону. При вычислении `d[i][j]` надо смотреть *назад*, на уже пройденную часть матрицы, а не вперед на "пустую" часть. При выбранном вами способе нумерации вам нужно вычислять значение элемента `d[i][j]` на основе анализа уже вычисленных значений `d[i][j - 1]`, `d[i + 1][j - 1]` и `d[i + 1][j]`:

```
d[i][j] = max(d[i][j - 1], max(d[i + 1][j - 1], d[i + 1][j])) + a[i][j];
```

---

Ну и, разумеется, при выбранном вами способе нумерации печатать в самом конце вам надо `d[1][n]`, а не `d[n][n]`.

---

Также, как правильно заметил @Harry, так как входные значения могу быть отрицательными, для того, чтобы использовать крайние элементы матрицы в качестве guard elements, нам не подходит значение `0` в этих элементах. Нам нужно чтобы они содержали некое "очень маленькое значение", т.е. не влияли на вычисление максимума.

То есть следует еще изначально проинициализировать `d` следующим образом

```
d[n + 1][0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  d[i][0] = INT_MIN; // std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
  d[n + 1][j] = INT_MIN; // std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

(Элемент `d[n + 1][0]` умышленно проинициализирован нулем).

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71b7165e3a1ea87e

Comment: можете показать , как делать ,я не слишком понял

Comment: то есть так   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    scanf("%d",&a[n-i][j]);
  a[0][1]=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    a[i][j]=max(a[i][j+1],max(a[i-1][j+1],a[i-1][j]))+a[i][j];
   // cout<<max(a[i][j+1],a[i-1][j+1])<<endl;

    printf("%d",a[n][n]);

Comment: я правильно понял ?

Comment: @Richard: У вас какая-то белиберда написана. С чего это вдруг `d` заменилось на `a`??? Вы, я смотрю, перекроили всю нумерацию. Я не буду разбираться с нуля. Мой ответ относится к вашей исходной реализации и нумерации.

Comment: @AnT с того, что они рядом на клавиатуре

Comment: @Igor: Я смотрю, что там сделаны более серьезные изменения. Больше похоже на попытку "сэкономить переменную" и обойтись вообще без `d`.

Comment: @AnT , а как сделать ,чтобы проверить пройденную часть матрицы ?

Comment: @Richard: Как я понимаю, это не ваш код? Ибо в моем ответе все разжевано, но вы, похоже, этого в упор не видите.

Comment: @AnT мой код . Спасибо за объяснение ! теперь всё ясно !

Comment: @AnT 7 15 2 3 путь по которому идёт

Comment: @Richard: Хм... Верно. Это я где-то напортачил. В последней скобке знак неправильный. Исправлено http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5ac0f31e05c5f46

Comment: @AnT можете разобраться ?

Comment: @Richard: В последней скобке знак неправильный. Исправлено http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5ac0f31e05c5f46

Comment: да и вправду @AnT . не заметно сразу

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Ваш код неверно сработает, например, на данные 3
1 2 3
-4 15 -6
-7 -8 -9 - см. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90a5be286eff5c23 Правильный ответ не 16, а 13.

Comment: @Harry: Исправлено.